# Alt + D Not Working In Windows 11 File Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-11, shortcuts, alt

In Windows 10, I frequently use Alt + D to quickly highlight the path to the current folder in Windows File Explorer so it can quickly be copied. It's the same shortcut that can be used to highlight the URL in many web browsers too.

I just got a Windows 11 laptop and I noticed that pressing Alt + D doesn't do anything in File Explorer. Is there a setting I can change to get the behavior I used to get in Windows 10? Or is it gone forever in Windows 11?

I am on Windows 11 Pro version 23H2, build 22631.3155.

Comment: Not gone forever - works fine here. Native Windows 11 Pro.   Any Windows 11 Pro machine

Comment: @John, I edited my post to specify which version of Windows I'm using. Perhaps I have to change a setting somewhere to get it to work, or we're on different versions of Windows 11.

Comment: Windows 11 Pro version 23H2, build 22631.3155 here as well and no settings around this issue changed here.

Comment: Maybe try resetting Windows Explorer options. WE, Options, new subwindow, Reset button

Comment: @John, I tried resetting and still no luck.

Comment: I am not sure what was done to the operating system.  What you wish to have works fine. Try doing a Windows 11 repair install and keep everything.  Make sure you did not install 3rd party Start and Explorer Apps.